# ‘Linear’ intersection property of separable Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space. Denote $W(f,\varepsilon) = \{z\in X\colon \lvert\langle f,z\rangle\rvert < \varepsilon\}$ for some $f\in X^*$ .

Suppose that $U$ is an open set in $X$ such that whenever:

- $f\in X^*, \lVert f\rVert=1$,
- $U\subseteq W(f,1)$ and
- $W(f_1, \varepsilon) \cap \dotsb \cap W(f_n, \varepsilon) \subseteq U$ for some $f_1, \dotsc, f_n \in X^*$ and $\varepsilon > 0$,

then $f\in \operatorname{span}\{ f_1, \dotsc, f_n \}$.

Must the set of such functionals $f$ for which this holds be countable?

Comment: Can you do it in case $X$ is two-dimensional?